# Need to capture Click Event on a selected option using Chosen.js

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen.js to render styled select elements,.. however, I the ability to click an already selected option, to refire a modal.

Example: Chosen select has 5 choices, you select the 3rd and a modal displays with further options.. to edit those options, I would like to re-click that 3rd option in the Chosen Select.

So far,. chosen is only seeing change events.. and i can't 1) override where they are suppressing the click events or 2) create anything that would overcome the issue..

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CysLH/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="chosen_test">
    <option value="a"> a </option>
    <option value="b"> b </option>
    <option value="c"> d </option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#chosen_test").chosen();
    $(document).on("click",".active-result",function(){
       alert($(this).text()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: That works on jsfiddle but I cannot get it to work in our web app, which is unfortunately not publicly accessible. Thanks for the solution, I think this would work in most scenarios where there isn't something else suppressing the click!

Comment: If you can post a code snippet from your app, maybe we can figure out why it's not working

Comment: Wish I could. It's proprietary and most likely being suppressed by something else we've concocted in Durandal or Knockout. The above case DOES seem to work in the jsfiddle.. so, the code example above it great. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Just make sure that you bind the event exactly as shown in the code sample above (i.e bind it on the document element) because the div with the active-result class is created on run-time.